# Unity GUI Label text justification issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm running into an issue with GUI.Label in Unity3D.  If I display some text on the screen and display that EXACT same string 1 pixel down and 1 to the right, it works correctly 99.9% of the time:

```
        var old=GUI.color;
        var shadow=rec;
        shadow.x++; shadow.y++;
        GUI.color=Color.black;
        GUI.Label(shadow, txt, style);
        GUI.color=old;
        GUI.Label(rec, txt, style);
```

I've had this same code for years but I just recently discovered that a particular string will wrap text in the wrong place on the shadow text, even though they both have the same width in their rect's and same style.  What's even more strange is it won't do this every frame.  The text appears when I hover over something with my mouse and moving the mouse slightly will cause the shadow string to go back & forth, wrapping two different ways causing the shadow text to not coincide with the normal colored text.
Not an edge-of-screen issue either.  I'm using 2020.2.1f1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be related to the X position in rec (which came from the mouse position).  This position should be irrelevant, as it is the width that determines where the text will wrap.  It's a bug in Unity and I can't seem to find a work-around.

Comment: Which would be the particular string and could you provide the other values (`rec` and `style`) that allow to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sure! The rect is: (x:5.00, y:105.00, width:250.00, height:150.00)
The text is: Use this to bless most articles of clothing. Once blessed, it can never be looted from your corpse upon death.
And the style is:

            infoStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.GetStyle("Label"));
            infoStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
            infoStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
            infoStyle.fontSize = 12;
            infoStyle.font = comic;


Comic is loaded here:

        comic = (Font)Resources.Load("comic", typeof(Font));


Comic is standard Comic Sans.

Comment: I'm guessing upgrading my Unity version is my only hope....

Answer (score 0):

I should probably be using the newer UI system for displaying text and other 2D visuals over the screen but, for those who still use the ancient GUI system like I do, here was my final solution to Unity's word-wrapping bug.  When you've got thousands of lines of code doing something one way, it's not so easy to just abandon it and switch to a different method.  Here is a function I came up with that does shadow text.  It could probably be cleaned up and optimized though:

```
//Shadow text
if(Event.current.type==EventType.Layout) words = wordWrap(txt,style,(int)rec.width);

var old=GUI.color; var shadow=rec; shadow.x++; shadow.y++;
GUI.color=Color.black;
foreach(var line in words) {
   GUI.Label(shadow,line,style); shadow.y+=lastFontHgt;
}
GUI.color=old;
foreach(var line in words) {
   GUI.Label(rec,line,style); rec.y+=lastFontHgt;
}


int lastFontHgt=0;

//actual word-wrapping generation is in this function
List<string> wordWrap(string txt,GUIStyle style,int width) {
    var lines=new List<string>();
    if(txt==null||txt=="") return lines;
    var str="";
    var words=txt.Split(' ');
    var flag=false;
    for(int i=0;i<words.Length;i++) {
        var old=str;
        if(flag) str+=" "; str+=words[i];
        var size = style.CalcSize(new GUIContent(str)); lastFontHgt=(int)size.y;
        if(((int)size.x)>width) {
            if(!flag||old=="") { lines.Add(str); str=""; }
            else { lines.Add(old); str=words[i]; }
        } else flag=true;
    }
    if(str!="") lines.Add(str);
    return lines;
}
```